# System Font for TikZ axis values

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, mathspec

I need to have my graphs using a specific font - the labels are OK - fixed with `\usepackage{mathspec}`, but this doesn't seem to change the font for the values on the axes.
How can I get the whole image to use the same font? (Source Sans Pro)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%RGB Definitions
\definecolor{PG-Chem}{RGB}{5,114,118}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=2,ymin=0,
            xlabel = {This is the x-axis},
            ylabel = {This is the y-axis},
            xtick distance = 1,
            ymax=2500,
            ]
            \addplot[
            thick,
            mark=*,
            color=PG-Chem,
            ] table 
                {
                x   y
                3   519 
                4   900
                5   799
                6   1090
                7   1400
                8   1310
                9   1680
                10  2080
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
[...]
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}% default setting
\setmathfont[range={up,it}]{Source Sans Pro}
[...]
```

[image]

Comment: super - thanks!

Comment: actually, I am getting an error on the last line
Package fontspec Error: The font "Latin Modern Math" cannot be found. \setmathfont

Comment: then try `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}`  instead

Comment: That did it - thanks
for others - this line replaced the default setting line

Comment: Then you used `xelatex`, right?